# Rails 3, ActiveRecord, PostgreSQL - ".uniq" command doesn't work?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, uniq

I have following query:

```
Article.joins(:themes => [:users]).where(["articles.user_id != ?", current_user.id]).order("Random()").limit(15).uniq
```

and gives me the error

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...s"."user_id" WHERE (articles.user_id != 1) ORDER BY Random() L...
```

When I *update* the original query to

```
Article.joins(:themes => [:users]).where(["articles.user_id != ?", current_user.id]).order("Random()").limit(15)#.uniq
```

so the error is gone... In MySQL **.uniq** works, in PostgreSQL not. Exist any alternative?

Comment: Are you sure query with `uniq` returns different result?  Please show actual SQL queries for each variant (use `sql` method).

Comment: I am sure. When I used this query with MySQL database, so without `.uniq` it returned me also the same row, but with `.uniq` always unique row. In PostgreSQL if I use `.uniq`, I get the error specified above, if I don't use `.uniq`, so the error is gone, but I am getting also the same rows from DB.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As the error states `for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`.
Therefore, you must explicitly select for the clause you are ordering by.

Here is an example, it is similar to your case but generalize a bit.

```
Article.select('articles.*, RANDOM()')
       .joins(:users)
       .where(:column => 'whatever')
       .order('Random()')
       .uniq
       .limit(15)
```

So, explicitly include your `ORDER BY` clause (in this case `RANDOM()`) using `.select()`.  As shown above, in order for your query to return the Article attributes, you must explicitly select them also.

I hope this helps; good luck

Comment: Why must you even add what you are ordering by to the select clause in the first place in postgresql. If you are using a join, then the sql should be smart enough to know what to order by without explicitly declaring it in the select clause (especially since the select clause is intended to limit columns returned).

Comment: Doesn't the inclusion of `RANDOM()` completely negate the `DISTINCT` because it's taking a set of completely unique values into account? And as such you end up with duplicates records just as if you hadn't used the `DISTINCT` in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Just to enrich the thread with more examples, in case you have nested relations in the query, you can try with the following statement.

```
Person.find(params[:id]).cars.select('cars.*, lower(cars.name)').order("lower(cars.name) ASC")
```

In the given example, you're asking all the cars for a given person, ordered by model name (Audi, Ferrari, Porsche)

I don't think this is a better way, but may help to address this kind of situation thinking in objects and collections, instead of a relational (Database) way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the `.uniq` method is translated to a `DISTINCT` clause on the SQL.  PostgreSQL is picky (pickier than MySQL) -- all fields in the select list when using `DISTINCT` must be present in the `ORDER_BY` (and `GROUP_BY`) clauses.

It's a little unclear what you are attempting to do (a random ordering?).  In addition to posting the full SQL sent, if you could explain your objective, that might be helpful in finding an alternative.

Comment: Probably you're right, but exist any elegant way to integrate in the query above `DISTINCT` clausule? My current query is "pretty short", I can use `find_by_sql` and there straight forward to set `DISTINCT` clausule, but in this case would be the query much bigger.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded my 100% working and tested application from 3.1.1 to 3.2.7 and now have this same PG::Error.

I am using Cancan...

```
@users = User.accessible_by(current_ability).order('lname asc').uniq
```

Removing the .uniq solves the problem and it was not necessary anyway for this simple query.

Still looking through the change notes between 3.1.1 and 3.2.7 to see what caused this to break.